# Time difference 2 seconds between PHP and MySQL (EC2 and RDS on AWS)

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My web app is running on EC2 instance (ubuntu) and a database is on separate RDS mysql server, all on AWS (amazon web services).
I have noticed that there is 2 seconds time difference between PHP and MySQL times, which causes problems with just published articles that do not appear published right away.
Here is an example output.

```
MySQL time: 2016-04-26 17:35:28          from MySQL: SELECT now() 
PHP time: 2016-04-26 17:35:30            from PHP: date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

Timezone is set to US/Eastern on both servers (EC2 instance running Ubuntu 14.04,  and on RDS MySQL server (via custom parameter group)) and in PHP (in php.ini).

Is there a way to get the two times in sync?

Comment: NTP? (network time protocol)... personally, I'd  use only one box to set all times in the data, probably the database itself

Comment: Is NTP daemon configured and running on EC2 instance? [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html).

Comment: for this issue, you need contact AWS directly for help. Maybe the NTP service has issue on RDS instance (managed service) which is not in your control.